Flutter splash screen frozen on release version for random phone
I have a flutter app released on play store. No issues detected by Firebase crashlytics and working on most users phones.
But there is at least 2 users devices reported :

Oneplus 7T pro HD1913 on Android 12
Samsung A34 on Android 12

on which app freezes at 1st launch on splash screen with logo before authentication screen. Bug still remains after killing app and retry.
Not being successful to track this bug, i procured myself the same Oneplus 7T pro HD 1913 as the one of user but still cannot reproduce the bug met by the user same phone.
In my pub yaml, i use    flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.9
A clue on how to track/investigate on this bug?

As with any bug, you'll want to reproduce the environment conditions as closely as possible when replicating it. Even if you have the same phone as the user who experienced the crash, you still need to ensure the firmware was on the same update, same running background services (that can cause interference), etc...
However, just doing what you did is already a big indicator that this is probably an isolated user issue and not a problem with the phone itself, seeing as you can't replicate it with the stock version.
By the way you presented your question, it seems it's just 1 user experiencing this per phone. My first step would be to get other users with those phones to try it (much like you did yourself), if it still only happens to the original users who had the problem, then you can assume it's due to local changes/interference on their side. In that case, the best you can do is tell them to disable anything that that could be causing instability.
I can't speak for those exact phones but I have used flutter_native_splash across many (small) applications with a few users and never got freeze problems on splash reported to me. It's usually a pretty stable library seeing as what it does is mostly just write the images and colors you define into the specific config files for each platform's theme.
